# Finding static IP of server

Tags: ip, static-ip

I have access to a  server via its local IP (I use putty) and I know the server has a static IP, how can I found its static(fix) IP? Its OS is CentOS.

Comment: `curl http://canhazip.com/`

Comment: also: `curl http://wgetip.com/` `curl http://curlmyip.com/`

Comment: @xofer `jsonip.com` can be handy too.

Comment: Look at the edge router/firewall configuration? Hit `whatismyip.com` from the server in question?

Comment: `curl ip.tyk.nu`, `curl ifconfig.me`

Answer (score 3):

Enter `ifconfig` at the command line.

Comment: Note that ifconfig will show the actual IP address assigned to the network interface, where the external sources listed in comments/answers will show the IP as it appears to, er, those external sources. This may be different in some situations, so check both.

Answer (score 1):

For example:

`links -dump http://whatismyip.com | egrep "([0-9]+.){3}"`

Of course you can use another site, but this is one of most popular.

Comment: I assumed that there is some kind of NAT, and public IP is not known on host itself